# Apache Solr - why result scores from a sharded index are different from a non-sharded one?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I converted a Solr core into a collection with two shards, and modified the custom search component to make it work on distributed search. While testing the component, I noticed results of the sharded index matches the non sharded (with the same query parameters), the scores of individual documents differ. To elaborate, when I send q=X to the sharded and non-sharded indices, they both return documents A, B, C. However the documents from sharded core have the scores, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 whereas the ones from non-sharded core may have 0.2, 0.4, 0.7.

What is the underlying reason for the difference in the score? I am not too familiar with how exactly Lucene scores documents, so I am wondering is it worth worrying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene and therefore Solr makes use of the [Vector Space Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Space_Model). As such the inverse document frequency (IDF) is a factor within the calculation of relevancy.

And when it comes to sharding this has an effect. As is written [in the docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding)

> Solr does not calculate universal term/doc frequencies. For most large-scale implementations, it is not likely to matter that Solr calculates TD/IDF at the shard level. However, if your collection is heavily skewed in its distribution across servers, you may find misleading relevancy results in your searches. In general, it is probably best to randomly distribute documents to your shards.

Currently there is no shared IDF. This means that each shard (index) calculates the score based on the IDF it has within its own index. In short, the score of a document is influenced by the other documents that are indexed on the same shard. And as it is reasonable to have different documents in each shard, this means that the same document within a different shard will have a slightly different score, as it has other documents around it.

I write `Currently there is no shared IDF` as there is work going on to create a distributed IDF - as you can see [in SOLR-1632](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1632).